# Get Log of Every Revision, Regardless of Location

Tags: svn

Doing something like `svn log -l5 -v` will get me a log of the last 5 commits for the dir that I'm in, but it will skip over some revision numbers.  Is there a way to get all the revisions in order regardless of the location you exec `svn log` in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do it on the root URL of the repository, which you can get with `svn info`.

```
svn log -l5 -v <root URL>
```